# How to record a video using my camera and upload to wowza server in android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, wowza

How can i record a video using my android phone and uploaded to wowza server in android.i tried many codes .i can upload audio to wowza server using this code http://code.google.com/p/android-recorder/ .but i need video also.now i just want to record a video using my camera and just upload to wowza server .please help me.

Comment: do you want to record a local video and upload to the server or record the video using the rtmp streaming?

Comment: yes exactly,i need rtmp streaming.is there some example ?give me some examples .please.i tried almost 2 weeks for this,but until i did't get anything working

Comment: my suggestion for you is to develop using flex adobe air for mobile, this is the only way that I know it's possible to stream the camera to a wowza server from a mobile application http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices.html

Comment: but we need to develop it on android or java.

Comment: flex for mobile compile to android, sorry but i dont know about any solution to develop it in java

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that you need to record video in MP4 in android devices.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107270/Recording-and-Playing-Video-on-Android

After recording the video you need to upload this video to Wowza content directory.